# Headers not set node.js api push notification

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, push-notification

Hello im trying to set up push notifications for my webapp.

I'm getting my subscription like I should.

It saves it to my database correctly.

It sends my notification like it should if there only is ONE user in the db

and i want to send to more than only one user :)

Im using:

- Vue.js (framework)
- Axios (post)
- node.js (api)
- mongoDB (database)

Here's my post to API.

```
await axios({
          method: 'post',
          url: 'API',
          data: {
            subscription: JSON.stringify(subscription),
            storeId: storeId
          },
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        })
```

It registreres my post, but then i get an throw error. 
that  "Can't set headers after they are sent."

I'm using CORS in my app like this:

```
const cors = require('cors')

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors())
app.use(morgan('combined'))
```

The way I'm handling the post from my website is by finding my subscriptions and then map through and say foreach subscription

webpush

```
//subscribe routes
app.post('/pushNotification', (req, res) => {
  var storeId = req.body.storeId
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  console.log(storeId)
  if (req.body.storeId != null) {
    console.log('Test1')
    //get pushSubscription object

    //create payload
    const payload = JSON.stringify({ title: 'push test' })
    Push.find({
      "storeId": storeId
    },
    'subscription', function(error, response) {
      console.log('Test2')
      console.log(response)
      response.map(item => {
        res.status(201).json({});
        console.log('Test3')
        var subscription = item.subscription
        console.log(subscription)
        webpush.sendNotification(subscription, payload).catch(err => console.error(err));
      })
    })
  } else {
    res.send("failed")
  }
})
```

As i can read around somewhere is it im not setting headers or something right. I have used cors like in tutorials and stuff.

So it's like it is crashing because it iterates wrong. 
but i can't see how.

ERROR MESSAGE:

[image: error message]

Thanks in advance

Comment: you are getting this error because `res.status(201).json({})` has already set the headers and sent back the response to the client but `webpush.sendNotification` also trying to set the headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are getting this error because res.status(201).json({}) has already set the headers and sent back the response to the client but webpush.sendNotification also trying to set the headers.You should use only         `webpush.sendNotification(subscription, payload).catch(err => console.error(err));`

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! it works, but now i get a timeout after the notification is sent: 

`"Failed to load URL: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'URL' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 503."`

Comment: Add these to your request headers `Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'x-access-token`

Comment: in the res.setHeader?

Comment: `var options={headers: {
   "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*",
    '"Access-Control-Allow-Headers"': '"Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"'
  }}`

in Options parameter of `sendNotification(subscription,payload,options)`

Comment: is the syntax for the options on this right?, it gives an syntax error?

Comment: Remove extra quotes from the second key value pairs it's a JSON object.

Comment: okay, i write it like this: `var options = {
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"'
      }
    }` and it gives me an error on that "TypeError: Header name must be a valid HTTP Token ["[object Object]"]"

Comment: no,it should be like `var options = { headers:{
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
}}`

Comment: It still gives me the errors that : "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'MYURL' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 503."

Comment: does this have something to do with the trigger is send when i try to push?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180439/discussion-between-shubham-sharma-and-anders-bootsmann-larsen).

Answer (score 1):

`res.json([body])` sets the corresponding header and sends the result:

> Sends a JSON response. This method sends a response (with the correct content-type) that is the parameter converted to a JSON string using JSON.stringify().

So, first of all you don't need to set header manually. 
second, If the `response` has more than one item, since you can't send multiple result for a request, you shouldn't use `res.json` in a `map`.
Moreover, be aware of `webpush.sendNotification` that it may send a result too.

Comment: Thanks a lot! but now i get a timeout after the notification is sent: "Failed to load URL: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'URL' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 503."